# In newly cloned git repo, I cannot checkout to a new branch

Tags: git, linux-kernel

I just cloned linux kernel code, and then when I tried to checkout to a new branch, I found it failed because of local changes.

I am confused why newly cloned code could have so-called local changes?
In the end, I use "`git checkout -f -b xxx`" to checkout to the new branch by force to discard the local changes, but I still wonders whether there are are elegant way to checkout successfully rather than by force?

```
$ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
Cloning into 'linux-stable'...
remote: Counting objects: 5253622, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1189462/1189462), done.
remote: Total 5253622 (delta 4399195), reused 4796362 (delta 4030229)
Receiving objects: 100% (5253622/5253622), 1005.30 MiB | 576.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4399195/4399195), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Checking out files: 100% (54401/54401), done.

$cd linux-stable

$ git checkout -b linux-4.2.y origin/linux-4.2.y
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.h
        net/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.c
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting


$ git checkout -f -b linux-4.2.y origin/linux-4.2.y
Checking out files: 100% (28688/28688), done.
Branch linux-4.2.y set up to track remote branch linux-4.2.y from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'linux-4.2.y'
```

Comment: Have you checked what were the changes that prevented the checkout? I suspect "broken" line endings ('\n' vs '\r\n')

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that an extraneous process is effecting changes to your working directory.

To avoid this complication, just clone into your target branch specifically:

```
git clone \
-b linux-4.2.y \
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
```

Comment: This is very useful tip even though I still cannot find root cause for the locally changed files.